# execCommand('copy') works with onClick event but not with onLoad event

Tags: javascript, html

I am facing a problem with `execCommand('copy')`. It works with `onClick` event, but not with `onLoad` event. Why would this be?

Code in question:

```
function testSp() 
{ 
    var copyText = document.querySelector('#challenge'); 

    copyText.select(); 

    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful'; 

    if(msg == 'successful')
    {
        alert('copied to clipboard.');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Press ctrl+c to copy.');
    }
}

window.onload = testSp;
```

Comment: Without any code or context, you are bound to get close votes and down votes. Consider adding more information, a code sample.

Comment: The below code does not works - <script>
  function testSp()
  {
 var copyText = document.querySelector('#challenge');
            copyText.select();
            var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
            var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
            if(msg == 'successful')
                alert('copied to clipboard.');
            else
                alert('Press ctrl+c to copy.');
  window.onload=testSp;
</script>

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more information.

Comment: If you are directly executing the `copy` command, when the page is loaded, it returns `false` because you are not focused on a copyable element or text. But when you click on something, most probably a text input, then copy command works there.

Comment: But the select() works.

Comment: That's strange. Can you please write the code in the question, can't understand anything.

Comment: Good, wait for answers. `:)`

Comment: The code works well in Mozilla 42 but in Google Chrome 46.0.2490.80  it is creating trouble.